# Declaration error:Identifier already declared please help me solve it

Tags: remix, erc-20

[image: Blockquote]

I am having this issue while compiling code. please help to get rid of this error

Comment: Hi atif aman! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Please include the code as text, that way it is easier to compile and test.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have a function with the same name as an event.

The convention is to capitalize the first letter of an event. e.g. `Transfer` instead of `transfer`